# Sending email based on Status change in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am trying to send email notification to the user when the record status for my custom object 'Service__Request_c' is changed to 'closed'. but it's getting fired for every record having the status 'closed'. please help me with this.
my Apex method is below:

```
    public class ServiceRequestEmailHandler {
   public static void sendSingleEmail(List<Id> RecordId){
                for(Service_Request__c sR : [Select id, Name, Status__c, Customer_Email__c, Oil_Checks_Touchup_Cost__c, Total_External_Repair_Cost__c, Total_Internal_Repair_Cost__c, Total_Effort_Required__c, Total_Repair_Cost__c FROM Service_Request__c WHERE Id IN : RecordId]){
                if(sR.Status__c == 'Closed' && sR.Customer_Email__c !=null){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                sendTo.add(sR.Customer_Email__c);
                mail.setToAddresses(sendTo); 
                mail.setReplyTo('think4u007@gmail.com');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('ASD Servicing Company');
                List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
                mail.setSubject('Billing Deatils for the Servicing with ASD Company ');
                String body = '<html><body>Dear ' + sR.Name + ' Below are the details of Your biliing Details: </body></html>';
                 mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
   }          
  }  
}  
}
```

and my trigger is:

```
    trigger ServiceRequestEmail on Service_Request__c (after update) {
      if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
      List<Id> sRequest = new List<Id>();
        for(Service_Request__c  i:trigger.new) {
        sRequest.add(i.Id);
}
        ServiceRequestEmailHandler.sendSingleEmail(sRequest); 

}  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking through the trailhead on [triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro).

1. You have the list of objects in the trigger. No need to then
   re-query them. Loop through what you're given in the
   trigger context.
2. The reason it's firing on every record is because you're just
   checking that `Status == Closed`. Therefore, all records that meet
   that criteria when they're updated will send an email regardless if Status changed or not. You need to
   confirm the change is what you want (changed status to Closed).

You can use oldMap and newMap to do #2.

- oldMap contains the Id and relevant record before the update was made
  on the record
- newMap contains the Id and relevant record after the update was made
  on the record

The map's key is the Id of the record which you can use to pull the Service_Request__c record as it was before and after the udpate so you can confirm the change that happened is what you're after. Like this, when someone updates some random field on a closed record, it will not fire an email.

*note: I typed this in by hand so there may be typos/errors in syntax, but the gist of what you need to do is there.*

```
//in your trigger pass the old and new map
ServiceRequestEmailHandler.sendSingleEmail(trigger.oldMap, trigger.newMap);
```

```
 public static void sendSingleEmail(Map<Id, Service_Request__c> oldMap, Map<Id, Service_Request__c> newMap){
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
     for(Id serviceRequestId : newMap.keyset()){
         Service_Request__c oldServiceRequest = oldMap.get(serviceRequestId);
         Service_Request__c newServiceRequest = newMap.get(serviceRequestId);

         if(newServiceRequest.Status__c == 'Closed' && newServiceRequest.Status__c != oldServiceRequest.Status__c && newServiceRequest.Customer_Email__c !=null){
                //build message email message but don't send
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                //add relevant info/fields
                mailToSend.add(mail);
         }
    }  

    Messaging.sendEmail(mailToSend);
}
```